# How can I conditionally include a newline in a bash prompt *without a filler char*

Tags: bash, prompt

This is a rather esoteric question...

I want my bash prompt to break if it exceeds a certain number of characters. After the newline, I want a **colored** 2-char prompt. However, I'm stymied by the following catch 222:

1. If I use a function that `echo`s a newline if the prompt is too long and an empty string otherwise, bash throws away the newline:

   ```
   function checknewline {
     local d=$1
     if [ ${#d} -gt  30 ]; then
       echo $'\n'
     else
       echo ''
     fi
   }
   PS1="$STUFF\$(checknewline '\w')$PROMPTCHAR" #newline gets discarded
   ```
2. I can put in a filler char, but it has to go AFTER the newline. Then I have the filler char in the second line of my prompt, which I don't want.
3. If I attempt to include the 2-char colored prompt `$PROMPTCHAR` in the checknewline function, no combination of shell escaping or options to echo that I've discovered pass through both the newline, and the `\[...\]` required to make the color escape sequences in `$PROMPTCHAR` non-printing. If I don't use `\[...\]` of course cursor-up-ing through history is broken.

It's deeply annoying that `echo -e "\n\[\033[0;31m\]bob\[\033[0m\]"` prints `\[\]bob\[\]` -- does anyone know why, or a workaround?

Comment: ... what do you expect `echo -e "\n\[\033[0;31m\]bob\[\033[0m\]"` to print out?

Comment: ad 2), you can add `\r` to move the cursor to the first column. Oh, I almost forgot: maybe this question should be moved to [UNIX & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @MarkReed I do expect it to print what it does, I just wish that there was some way to have echo print prompt escape sequences

Comment: @Kenney I did try octal & hex for the \[, but no go.

Comment: Oh ok - I had similar trouble with tcsh. In vi you can insert ^] (control-]) via `i control-V control-]`, maybe that helps?

Comment: I got the prompt I wanted but without answering the question of how to have functions emit prompt escape characters. What I did was: 1. emit the color sequence for the first prompt char, 2. checknewline includes the first prompt char in both branches with no color codes, with a newline when desired; 3. emit the color coded second prompt char

Comment: @Kenney I tried echo -e $'\c['$COLORCODE$'\c]'. Nothing was printed, but the colorcode characters were not interpreted as non-printing.

Comment: try `echo -e "\x1b[1;33mTest"` (no control codes) on the command line. If that doesn't work, your terminal doesn't support ANSI codes.

Comment: it works in echo, but bash prompt then doesn't recognize the sequence as indicating non-printing, same as with `$'\c['..$'\c]'`. No idea why.